# Load HTML page dynamically into div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so when I click on a link in a HTML page, it dynamically loads the requested page into a div with jQuery.

How can I do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // what can I do for load any url clicked?
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>

<a href="page1.html">Page 1</a><br />
<a href="page2.html">Page 2</a><br />
<a href="page3.html">Page 3</a><br />
<a href="page4.html">Page 4</a><br />
<a href="page5.html">Page 5</a><br />
<a href="page6.html">Page 6</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You hava an opening `iframe` tag followed by a closing `div` tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a jQuery plugin out there called [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) it states: "It's ajax with real permalinks, page titles, and a working back button that fully degrades."

The plugin uses HTML5 pushState and AJAX to dynamically change pages without a full load. If pushState isn't supported, PJAX performs a full page load, ensuring backwards compatibility.

What pjax does is that it listens on specified page elements such as `<a>`. Then when the `<a href=""></a>` element is invoked, the target page is fetched with either the `X-PJAX` header, or a specified fragment.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
</script>
```

Putting this code in the page header will listen on all links in the document and set the element that you are both fetching from the new page and replacing on the current page.

(meaning you want to replace `#pjax-container` on the current page with `#pjax-container` from the remote page)

When `<a>` is invoked, it will fetch the link with the request header `X-PJAX` and will look for the contents of `#pjax-container` in the result. If the result is `#pjax-container`, the container on the current page will be replaced with the new result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pjax.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container');
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Site</h1>
  <div class="container" id="pjax-container">
    Go to <a href="/page2">next page</a>.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If `#pjax-container` is not the first element found in the response, PJAX will not recognize the content and perform a full page load on the requested link. To fix this, the server backend code would need to be set to only send `#pjax-container`.

Example server side code of `page2`:

```
//if header X-PJAX == true in request headers, send
<div class="container" id="pjax-container">
  Go to <a href="/page1">next page</a>.
</div>
//else send full page
```

If you can't change server-side code, then the fragment option is an alternative.

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container', { 
  fragment: '#pjax-container' 
});
```

Note that `fragment` is an older pjax option and appears to fetch the child element of requested element.

Answer (score 6):

JQuery load works, but it will strip out javascript and other elements from the source page.  This makes sense because you might not want to introduce bad script on your page.  I think this is a limitation and since you are doing a whole page and not just a div on the source page, you might not want to use it.  (I am not sure about css, but I think it would also get stripped)

In this example, if you put a tag around the body of your source page, it will grab anything in between the tags and won't strip anything out.  I wrap my source page with  and .

This solution will grab everything between the above delimiters.  I feel it is a much more robust solution than a simple load.

```
  var content = $('.contentDiv');
    content.load(urlAddress, function (response, status, xhr) {
        var fullPageTextAsString = response;
        var pageTextBetweenDelimiters = fullPageTextAsString.substring(fullPageTextAsString.indexOf("<jqueryloadmarkerstart />"), fullPageTextAsString.indexOf("<jqueryloadmarkerend />"));
        content.html(pageTextBetweenDelimiters);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

and make sure to call this library first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: this will just add the `src-attribute` to the div.

Comment: This will only work when `#content` is an iframe or the loading website is a non-external site.

Comment: his all pages are local so there won't be any issue in loading those in div.

Answer (score 5):

I think this would do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $(".divlink").click(function(){
         $("#content").attr("src" , $(this).attr("ref"));

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="content"></iframe>

<a href="#" ref="page1.html" class="divlink" >Page 1</a><br />
<a href="#" ref="page2.html" class="divlink" >Page 2</a><br />
<a href="#" ref="page3.html" class="divlink" >Page 3</a><br />
<a href="#" ref="page4.html" class="divlink" >Page 4</a><br />
<a href="#" ref="page5.html" class="divlink" >Page 5</a><br />
<a href="#" ref="page6.html" class="divlink" >Page 6</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

By the way if you can avoid Jquery, you can just use the `target` attribute of `<a>` element:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="content" name="content"></iframe>

<a href="page1.html" target="content" >Page 1</a><br />
<a href="page2.html" target="content" >Page 2</a><br />
<a href="page3.html" target="content" >Page 3</a><br />
<a href="page4.html" target="content" >Page 4</a><br />
<a href="page5.html" target="content" >Page 5</a><br />
<a href="page6.html" target="content" >Page 6</a><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [Jquery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function. You would just use that function with an onclick function tied to the a tag or a button if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's getJSON() or Load(); with the latter, you can reference an existing html file. For more details, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/661782/Three-Ways-to-Dynamically-Load-HTML-Content-into-a

Answer (score 1):

You can through **option**

Try this with some modifications

```
<div trbidi="on">
<script type="text/javascript">
function MostrarVideo(idYouTube)
{
var contenedor = document.getElementById('divInnerVideo');
if(idYouTube == '')
{contenedor.innerHTML = '';
} else{
var url = idYouTube;
contenedor.innerHTML = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ url +'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
}
</script>


<select onchange="MostrarVideo(this.value);">
<option selected disabled>please selected </option>
<option value="qycqF1CWcXg">test1</option>
<option value="hniPHaBgvWk">test2</option>
<option value="bOQA33VNo7w">test3</option>
</select>
<div id="divInnerVideo">
</div>
```

If you want to put a default page placed inside **id="divInnerVideo"**

example:

```
<div id="divInnerVideo">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/pES8SezkV8w?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```