# Html not loading dynamically into Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, clearfix

I've been able to use answers provided at [Load HTML page dynamically into div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735762/load-html-page-dynamically-into-div-with-jquery) to perfectly load html into divs in the past, however, with a new project that I've started which is based off of a codrops template [(multi-level push menu)](http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html), the pages do not load into the designated **.content** div

The webpage is **[here](http://georgiesgourmetcatering.com/upload/artsitemap)**. I've loaded all the proper jquery libs, and the test page "bio.html" is properly pathed.

I am working very specifically on the first **ul li** menu list link **"Biography"** to just test the functionality of it.

The code I'm using in jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bio").click(function(){
        $('.content').load('bio.html');
        //alert("Thanks for visiting!");
    }); 
});
```

The selector "#bio" has been applied to

> `<li><a class="icon icon-male" id="bio">Biography</a></li>`

in index.html. In the class="content" div tag I have it's css set to

```
.content {
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0 );
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3em 2em;
    max-width: 1200px;
    max-height: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

I don't know if any of the above code is interfering with whatever is not allowing the page to load dynamically when handler is clicked. I did make a change to **class="content"** from **class="content clearfix"** because I'm not too concerned about using the clearfix hack at the moment, which was the only change in identifying the element in the original codrops html.

Comment: i get `$ is not defined ` in my console , anyone also get the same.

Comment: Yeah, `js/linking.js` should be included after jQuery.

Comment: I think it might be because you have references to 2 different versions of jQuery (1.4 & 1.6). Can you try removing one of them?

Comment: That was exactly the issue, thank you very much! I'm sure I've been doing that same error for some time. I removed the 1.4 library and moved the linking.js after. worked beautifully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you called jQuery library after your script ,
call jQuery first and then your script

[image]

and i encourage you to use 1.9.0 or later version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link you are loading your jquery file after your code therefor '$' is not defined move your jquery library above that and it should start working.