# What's wrong with this frames?

Tags: html, frames

> http://jsfiddle.net/k8mycshL/

```
<frameset rows="10%,*">
  <frame src="menu.html">
  <frame src="sites.html">
  </frameset>
```

Hi there. I was trying to make a frame setup but it doesn't work :'( 
Could you help me? Let's say the menu.html and sites.html are just normal pages, so I don't think I should upload those..

I'd like it to be kinda like this:
[[wireframe] (http://framebox.org/rRXX)](http://framebox.org/rRXX)
Where in the menu there are links external sites which will be displayed in the other section

Thanks in advance!
Robin van der Noord

Comment: Don't use frames. Also what's not working about it?

Comment: Yeah I know... But what else should I use? CSS probably huh? @Lee

Comment: @APAD1 well it just doesn't display anything. Neither locally as on my testing website [here it should display the frames] (http://rvdnproductonstest1.net78.net/tumblr.html)

Comment: Are those pages, `menu.html` and `sites.html` at the same directory as your frameset page?

Comment: Definitely CSS. You could use inline-blocks, which would all then condense into vertical blocks on mobiles

Comment: @LcSalazar yes they are as you can see on [this page] (http://rvdnproductonstest1.net78.net)

Comment: @vico wow you really helped me with that ;)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're approaching it this way? Why not just have all the HTML in a single page and use divs to break the content up?

Comment: Because later on I want to use the menu.html to load different iframes in the other part of the screen, kinda like tabs in your browser @APAD1

Comment: PHP would be a better solution.

Comment: @APAD1 maybe but I don't speak PHP that good ;)

Comment: And I'd like my website to be pure html/css(/js)

Comment: But thanks for all your advice but first I'd like to know why the frames don't work???

Comment: Couldn't tell ya, it's working perfectly fine for me. The only potential issue I could see is that your 2 html files are not in the same folder as the index page as @LcSalazar suggested.

Comment: Maybe it's my browsers I'll test it on another computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it is preferable to avoid using frames.

But in answer your question, `frameset` should not be included in the `body` element.

Try it at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_frame_cols

Comment: What would you suggest, CSS or PHP.
Because if you say PHP I can give up my project ;)

Comment: If your website **must** be pure html/css(/js), then PHP can't be an option :P If it's a small web with css you can be fine. If not you could end up with a huge html. Then maybe I would try loading with js (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735762/load-html-page-dynamically-into-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Well I'm going to build something around it so it's a mac app, and my method doesn't accept php so yeah. It's going to be mostly iframes so it's small indeed

Comment: Thanks I'll try the js-loading