# How to append HTML string to div via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I really have big difficulties with Ajax, this time I'm not able to append some HTML code to a div.

I need to append to `<div id="content-loader"></div>` this HTML string

**PHP**

```
function getLogo(){
    $logo = '<div class="bg-logo-loading"></div>
            <div class="logo-loading-container">
                <div class="logo-loading-inner">
                    <div class="logo-loading">
                      <div></div>
                      <div></div>
                      <div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $logo;
}
```

Using this Ajax POST:

**JS**

```
function showLoader(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl+"/requests/get_Logo.php",
        dataType : 'html',
        cache: false,
        success : function(html){
            $('#content-loader').html($(html.content).text());
        }
    });
}
```

**get_Logo.php**

```
<?php
include("../includes/config.php");
include("../includes/classes.php");

$feed = new feed();
echo $feed->getLogoLoading();
?>
```

Is there any chance to make it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load HTML page dynamically into div with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735762/load-html-page-dynamically-into-div-with-jquery)

Comment: @Ozan I don't think it's a duplicate, my problem here is related to an Ajax POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting html in response then simply just put it inside of your `content-loader` div using jQuery's html method. like this

```
success : function(html) {
    $('#content-loader').html(html);
```